# Looping in Mata with OLS

Tags: stata

I need help with looping in Mata. I have to write a code for Beta coefficients for OLS in Mata using a loop. I am not sure how to call for the variables and create the code. Here is what I have so far.

```
foreach j of local X {
if { //for X'X
    matrix XX = [mata:XX = cross(X,1  ,  X,1)]
    XX
} 
else {
      mata:Xy = cross(X,1  , y,0)
      Xy
}
```

I am getting an error message "invalid syntax".

Comment: `else {` needs it's own line, and you need to close the `}` after `foreach` (I've suggested this as an edit to your question). It will help if you put together a working example using one of the example datasets, e.g. `sysuse auto`

Comment: It is also not clear to me why you are looping. I'm going to post an example of an OLS regression using mata, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need the loop for. Perhaps you can provide more information about that. However the following example may help you implement OLS in `mata`.

Load example data from `bcuse`:

```
ssc install bcuse
clear 
bcuse bwght
```

```
mata

x = st_data(., ("male", "parity","lfaminc","packs"))
cons = J(rows(x), 1, 1)
X = (x, cons)
y = st_data(., ("lbwght"))
beta_hat = (invsym(X'*X))*(X'*y)
e_hat = y - X * beta_hat
s2 = (1 / (rows(X) - cols(X))) * (e_hat' * e_hat)
B = J(cols(X), cols(X), 0)
n = rows(X)
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    B =B+(e_hat[i,1]*X[i,.])'*(e_hat[i,1]*X[i,.])
    }
V_robust = (n/(n-cols(X)))*invsym(X'*X)*B*invsym(X'*X)
se_robust = sqrt(diagonal(V_robust))
V_ols = s2 * invsym(X'*X)
se_ols = sqrt(diagonal(V_ols))

beta_hat
se_robust

end
```

This is far from the only way to implement OLS using `mata`. [See the Stata Blog for another example using `quadcross`](https://blog.stata.com/2016/01/05/programming-an-estimation-command-in-stata-computing-ols-objects-in-mata/), I like my example because it preserves a little more of the matrix algebra in the code.